# ksh script optimization

Tags: optimization, file-io, ksh

I have a small script that simply reads each line of a file, retrieves id field, runs utility to get the name and appends the name at the end. The problem is the input file is huge (2GB). Since output is same as input with a 10-30 char name appended, it is of the same order of magnitude. How can I optimize it to read large buffers, process in buffers and then write buffers to the file so the number of file accesses are minimized?

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read line
do
    id=`echo ${line}|cut -d',' -f 3`

    NAME=$(id2name ${id} | cut -d':' -f 4)

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        NAME="ERROR"
        echo "Error getting name from id2name for id: ${id}"
    fi

    echo "${line},\"${NAME}\"" >> ${MYFILE}
done < ${MYFILE}.csv
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed things up considerably by eliminating the two calls to `cut` in each iteration of the loop. It also might be faster to move the redirection to your output file to the end of the loop. Since you don't show an example of an input line, or what `id2name` consists of (it's possible it's a bottleneck) or what its output looks like, I can only offer this approximation:

```
#!/bin/ksh
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2 id remainder   # use appropriate var names
do
    line=$field1,$field2,$id,$remainder
    # warning - reused variables
    IFS=: read -r field1 field2 field3 NAME remainder <<< $(id2name "$id")
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        NAME="ERROR"
        # if you want this message to go to stderr instead of being included in the output file include the >&2 as I've done here
        echo "Error getting name from id2name for id: ${id}" >&2  
    fi
    echo "${line},\"${NAME}\""
done < "${MYFILE}.csv" > "${MYFILE}"
```

The OS will do the buffering for you.

**Edit:**

If your version of ksh doesn't have `<<<`, try this:

```
    id2name "$id" | IFS=: read -r field1 field2 field3 NAME remainder
```

(If you were using Bash, this wouldn't work.)

Comment: Thanks Dennis. id2name gets the user name based on the id and I have no control over the utility. However, I want to has the ids and the corresponding names and do a local look up before hitting the db. I tried typeset -A , however it is not recognized under ksh. Unfortunately on SunOS, ksh93 is not available. Is there any alternative solution? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, getting syntax error for the line: IFS=: read -r field1 field2 field3 NAME remainder <<< $(id2name $id)

 syntax error at line 9 : `<' unexpected
Is it << instead of <<< or is my interpretor bad version?

Comment: Thanks, that works. Also, its going much faster now, due to removal of cut and using OS buffering!